# Does lazy-init actually work as advertised?

Tags: spring

According to the documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init the below should not be instatiating `MyDatabase` yet I can clearly see this is the case in the `afterPropertiesSet` method of the `HibernateDatabase` class when debugging. If I remove `MyDatabaseEntityManagerFactory` then this does not occur. However this should not matter given that `MyDatabaseEntityManagerFactory` is also lazy - it should not cause `MyDatabase` to initialise.

Either I'm misunderstanding the part of the docs that say that a lazy bean referencing another lazy bean shouldn't cause it to initialise or there is a fundamental problem in Spring here. Can anyone shed some light on this or possibly suggest an alternative to what I want to achieve?

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="false">
    <bean id="HibernateDatabase" class="mypackage.database.HibernateDatabase"
        abstract="true" />

    <bean id="MyDatabase" parent="HibernateDatabase" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="driver" value="com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver" />
        <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect" />
        <property name="url" value="${My.dburl}" />
        <property name="user" value="${My.dbuser}" />
        <property name="password" value="${My.dbpassword}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="EntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
        abstract="true">
        <property name="targetMethod" value="getEntityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="MyDatabaseEntityManagerFactory" parent="EntityManagerFactory" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="MyDatabase" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Are you using `MyDatabaseEntityManagerFactory` as a reference in another bean?

Comment: Not in this case - this is basically a utility definition and apps that need the DB reference would be referencing the entities as required but otherwise importing this XML shouldn't have any effect. It's the fact that it was instatiating them in an app where I had no need of the database that led to this question. Removing the definition proved nothing was referencing it (otherwise Spring would complain about missing references).

Comment: Think it might be useful to see why Spring thinks it needs to instantiate the bean. Can you put Spring into DEBUG logging so that we can see what dependency it is trying to satisfy, hence why it creates the bean?

Comment: I think it might be this as it occurs right before it calls afterPropertiesSet(): org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory Eagerly caching bean 'MyDatabase' to allow for resolving potential circular references

Comment: In order to determine that the import portion is not responsible I moved the definition into my main Spring for the database definitions above. The only thing that seems to make a difference is whether or not I define MyDatabaseEntityManagerFactory. If I don't then I basically get no debug logging about MkvDatabase other than it being listed in Pre-instantiating singletons (although from the code that doesn't look to care about any of this and just lists all definitions).